# is it possible to set the page count for the silverlight datapager control

Tags: silverlight, datapager

hi is it possible to set the page count for the silverlight datapager control with no itemsource for the datpager.

if not possible is there any other equivalent controls to use as datapager in silverlight

Answer (score 0):

Implement the IPagedCollectionView from your code behind and you'll have access to the TotalItemCount property that will allow you to set the total number of items.  You can then set the page size and what page index you are currently on.  ItemCount will be the total number of itmes returned and the datapager should take care of the rest.